# Sequelize instance methods with typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I'm trying to implement toJSON() instance method of sequelize, like this:

```
  sequelize.define<UserInstance, UserAttribute>("User", UserValidation, {
      instanceMethods: {
          toJSON: () => {
              console.log(this); // undefined
          }
      }
  })
```

the this object is undefined. If I put the option object in its own variable, the this object points to the module object.
Oddly, the vscode debugger sees the this object correctly, i.e. pointing to the instance.

Comment: Try to use function instead of arrow function. `toJSON: function(){...`

Comment: that did the job! thank you

Comment: FWIW, Sequelize instances already have a toJSON() method...